# Open AI GPT API: How to get completion in between (fill-in-the-middle)?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

In this announcement: https://openai.com/blog/gpt-3-edit-insert, an insert mode that lets you have completion in the middle of a text is introduced. How can I have it through the Open AI GPT models' completion API?

For instance in the case of a code completion (which Github Copilot does currently):

```py
def say_hello():
    print('hi', name)
```

should be completed with `name` argument inside the parentheses:

```py
def say_hello(name):
    print('hi', name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [insertion instruction guide](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/inserting-text) explains, we can use `suffix` parameter to provide the text which is located after where you want to insert the new completion.

```py
prompt = "def say_hello("
suffix = """):
  print('hi', name)"""

response = client.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
    prompt=prompt,
    suffix=suffix,
    max_tokens=32
)
print(response.choices[0].text) # should be 'name'
```